# App Indexing through mobile application

Tags: android, firebase, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I have used this Firebase Tutorial URL <https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/public-content> for integrating App Indexing in my Android and iOS application.

I reviewed the sample application provided and it is working fine, but when I am integrating it in my application, but in my AndroidManifest.xml I got confused with this following code snippet:

```
 <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="recipe-app.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/recipe" />
```

My questions are:

- What is recipe-app.com and pathPrefix, what are the things I need to do to make App Indexing work in my application?
- Is there any descriptive tutorials for Integrating App Indexing in Android apart from Firebase official link?
- Where should I put digital assets link file on the server?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure I will make sure from now onwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="recipe-app.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/recipe" />
```

This is how you declare that you app handles certain URLs. The idea is that App Indexing builds on top of app links, which are a way of having your app handle regular web URLs.

So if your app is "MyApp" and you have "myapp.com" you would change the `android:host` value to "myapp.com". The path is for if your app only handles a subset of the paths on your site. For example, if you have a forum under `/forum` and a pricing calculator under `/calculator` and your app only implements the calculator, you would use:

```
 <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="myapp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/calculator" />
```